# Greedy Algorithms. How to solve this problem?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose you are given two sets A and B, each containing n positive integers. You can choose to reorder each set however you like. After reordering let ai be the i-th element of set A, and let bi be the i-th element of set B. You then receive a payoff of (a1 ^ b1) × (a2 ^ b2) × ... × (an ^  bn). Give a polynomial algorithm that will maximize the payoff.

Answer:
I think if we sort both sets increasingly, the problem will solve. It needs o(nlog(n)) time. 
Does anyone have a counterexample?

Comment: There's many ways to solve the problem. If you're completely stuck on how to solve it, a good starting point might be to try implementing the brute force approach, where you calculate every possible combination of orderings, and the corresponding payoff. Looking at which orderings in the brute force output pay well and which pay poorly may reveal additional structure that you can exploit to solve the problem more efficiently.

Comment: Is that `power` or `xor`?

Comment: I think brute force is not a polynomial algorithm because it has an exponential increasing.

Comment: "^" is power and "×" is multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's straightforward to prove that the greedy algorithm - i.e. pair the largest number with the largest exponent, then the next-largest number with the next-largest exponent, and so on - is optimal.

Suppose the product includes two terms `a[i] ** b[i]` and `a[j] ** b[j]`, where `a[i] < a[j]` and `b[i] > b[j]`. It follows that `(a[i] ** b[j]) * (a[j] ** b[i])` is greater than `(a[i] ** b[i]) * (a[j] ** b[j])` because they differ by a factor of `(a[j] / a[i]) ** (b[i] - b[j])`, which by assumption is a number greater than 1 to the power of a number greater than 0, so this factor is greater than 1. Therefore, we can improve the payoff by swapping `b[i]` with `b[j]`, and hence the original payout was not optimal because it could be improved upon by making the swap.

It follows that your greedy algorithm is correct in the sense that it does indeed maximise the payoff.

Comment: Thanks for your proof. I think proving Greedy Algorithms are more based on contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, we can reduce the problem to another simple version. If you `log` from the formula we will have:

```
b1 log(a1) + ... + bn log(an)
```

Now suppose we have two vectors `V1 = <b1, b2, ..., bn>` and `V2 = <a1, a2, ..., an>`. Hence, the formula is the dot product of these two vectors (`V1.V2`). By the definition of the dot product we know that `V1.V2 = |V1|*|V2|* cos(theta)`. By permutating the elements of `V1` and `V2` we know the norm of `V1` and `V2` will not change. Hence, we need to maximize  `cos(theta)` (that `theta` is the degree between `V1` and `V2`). So, we need to minimize `theta` (to maximize `cos(theta)`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but solving this problem is as hard as that one. I think if we sort both sets increasingly, then the problem will solve, and payoff will be maximized.

Comment: I think you have reduced it to a more difficult problem. If you posed this problem (minimize the angle between two vectors), I would start by turning it into a dot product to get rid of the trigonometric function.

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be an easier way to compare (a<sub>i</sub>^b<sub>j</sub> * a<sub>j</sub>^b<sub>i</sub>) with (a<sub>i</sub>^b<sub>i</sub> * a<sub>j</sub>^b<sub>j</sub>) when a<sub>i</sub> < a<sub>j</sub> and b<sub>i</sub> > b<sub>j</sub>, that is to take the logarithm of both. Then the problem transfers to compare the value of b<sub>j</sub>log(a<sub>i</sub>) + b<sub>i</sub>log(a<sub>j</sub>) and b<sub>i</sub>log(a<sub>i</sub>) + b<sub>j</sub>log(a<sub>j</sub>), and then we can do a simple subtraction operation. And it is easy to tell (b<sub>i</sub> - b<sub>j</sub>)log(a<sub>j</sub>) > (b<sub>i</sub> - b<sub>j</sub>)log(a<sub>i</sub>). So, b<sub>j</sub>log(a<sub>i</sub>) + b<sub>i</sub>log(a<sub>j</sub>) > b<sub>i</sub>log(a<sub>i</sub>) + b<sub>j</sub>log(a<sub>j</sub>) => a<sub>i</sub>^b<sub>j</sub> * a<sub>j</sub>^b<sub>i</sub> > a<sub>i</sub>^b<sub>i</sub> * a<sub>j</sub>^b<sub>j</sub>.